# Physics for a organization scheme

Tags: javascript, html, physics, organization

I've been trying to create something (much more basic) as in the video linked below:

http://blog.theclinic.eu/?p=653 (Should start at 14:30 ish)

It's a talk by John Maeda & he demonstrates his application called Powershop. I've been trying to recreate something that had the same effect, but I can't figure out how I could make the circles stay at a distance like that without collision, any suggestions on how to approach it?

I've tried to make the constraints have a min & max distance so that they'd follow around, I tried to let circles orbit, but none seems to look like his.

I'm trying this with javascript/ HTML5, but I would just like some tips or suggestions on the approach! (My physics/math knowledge is limited, so I might be missing out on some obvious concept to apply?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with velocity, acceleration and friction?

Comment: Just an idea that popped into my head: [`gource`](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) is an open-source program that is somewhat similar to what you showed (it's a source-code history visualization). Perhaps poking around its code may give you some ideas.

Comment: I am familiar with velocity,... . The setup I had now has collision & let's the ball bounce off at the correct speed/angle for their mass

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to make this work without learning a little more physics, namely acceleration and dissipative forces. Any basic physics textbook will cover it in the first two chapters. Basically you want three different influences acting on each dot: a force (or displacement) representing the rigid links, a repulsive force between dots which grows weaker with distance, and a frictional force which increases with speed.

Comment: Thanks, at least I understood what you mean, and it seems to make sense, so I'll try to take it from there.

Comment: The Collusion plugin from Mozilla (HTML5 + JavaScript) provides similar visualisation of the tracking cookies that different sites install in your browser. Just an idea: the links are hard springs, the balls have repulsive charges and move in a dampening media. The whole process can be simulated using fast and not very accurate physics solver. If you follow the `physics` tag here, there are many question concerning existing physics engines. I believe most of them would suffice for your purposes.

Comment: Look no further than [here](http://code.google.com/p/box2d-html5/) :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hristo, I used the ideas from Beta to implement something basic that seems to be pretty close for a first try! I'll check out your links as well, thanks! I'd accept the answers but... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a nice canned solution, instead of building everything from the ground up, I suggest you look at [Box2D](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/).

The system you see in the Powershop graphics is a simple physical model where each "ball" or "node" or whathaveyou is a charged object that repels all the other balls/nodes. If you model the system as a collection of points connected by freely-rotating lines, all you have to do is understand a little physics to get this effect working with Box2D.  Namely, like charges repel.

It should be that easy.  You will constrain a set of points so that each has to stay within a length L from a center, and this will be your model of the arms all the balls rotate on. Then you will give each point the exact same charge and they will repel each other and spread out evenly with nice bouncy effects.

(The part where you get creative is how you want to add a whole new collection of points, like when the speaker in your Powershop talk clicks on a node.)